# What is the best way to find out the asymptotical behaviour of the sequence $n^{2/n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the best way to find out the asymptotical behaviour of this sequence?
$$a(n)=(n^2)^{1/n}\qquad n \in\Bbb N$$

Comment: The best way: leave it as it is.

Comment: Hint : Write $(n^2)^{1/n}=e^{(2/n)\log n}$.

Comment: why not n^(2/n)?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are after, but it may help to write it as $(n^{1/n})^2$ and then see what $n^{1/n}$ does, which you might know.

Answer (score 1):

as @confused mentioned u should use logarithm , the reason is logarithm has good behaviour with powers as you know $log(a^n)=nlog(a)$ so the idea is take logarithm from the both sides , $log{a_n}=2log(n)/n$ so as n goes to infinity $log(n)/n$ become zero so $loga_n=0$ as n goes to infinity and at last $a_n=e^0=1$ this is great mthod agains power like series.

Comment: why cannot i just reason that as n goes to infinity the expresison goes to n^0 which goes to 1?

Answer (score 0):

First, analyze the behaviour of $n^{1/n}$ as $n\to\infty$.
This should make it easier to find out what happens $n^{2/n}={\left(n^{1/n}\right)}^2$ as $n\to\infty$.

With $a_n=n^{1/n}$, write $a_n=1+d_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
It's easy to see that $a_n>1$ for all $n>1$, so $d_n>0$ for all $n>1$.
Now, by the binomial theorem we have

$$n=a_n^n=(1+d_n)^n\geq 1+\binom{n}2d_n^2\,.$$

This implies

$$0<d_n^2<\frac{2(n-1)}{n(n-1)}=\frac2n,$$

so that by the squeeze theorem $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n^2=0$. It follows that $d_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, and so $a_n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.